# How to keep a GET-param alive in Symfony 1.4 Backend-module?

Tags: php, symfony1, get, symfony-1.4, parameter-passing

I built a SF 1.4-backend-module, which needs to be kind of "pre-filtered". So I added the GET-parameter ?type=A to the menue-link.

Now I need to "keep this param alive" within the module when clicking on "edit", "delete", ...

Is there an easy way to keep this get-param all within the module or even a better way to pass a fixed value to the module?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Instead of using a get parameter, which doesn't always work, you should better store this information into the session. Filter are getting from the session and from the form (when you submit it).

For example, if you want to filter by author on the book listing a certain FK, use this snippet before going to the page or in the `preExecute()` of book:

```
$this->getUser()->setAttribute(
  'book.filters', 
  array('author _id' => $author->getId()), 
  'admin_module'
);
```